# Reset Google SSO login in on sign out

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, google-signin

I currently have Google Sign-In for Websites working for signing in and out, and on signing out redirecting them to the login page. When the user clicks sign in again, it retains the last email that was used to sign in and signs them in with that.

What I'm looking to do is when the user signs out, it resets the sign in button to ask for a email and password again. This sign in will be on a shared computer, and will need everyone that uses this site will need to log in with their own email every time.

I have tried resetting all cookies on sign out, but still retains the info.

Below is my sign in button and sign out button. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Sign in button:

```
<a onclick="signIn();">Sign In</a>
<script>
  function signIn() {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signIn().then(function () {
      console.log('User signed in.');

    window.location = "/logging-in.html";

    });
  }
</script>
```

Sign out button

```
<a onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>
<script>
  function signOut() {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut().then(function () {
       auth2.disconnect();
     window.location.href="/logging-out.html";
      console.log('User signed out.');
    });
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function signOut() {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();

    auth2.disconnect();

    auth2.signOut().then(function () {       
       window.location.href="/logging-out.html";
       console.log('User signed out.');
    });
}
```

Comment: Please add some context to your answer, this will increase it value for future visitors as well as the person asking the question.